# Finding a basis for span of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, span

$U = \text{span}\{(1,0,0),(0,2,-1)\}$, $W = \text{span}\{(0,1,-1)\}$.
How can I find bases for $U$ and $W$? (I think they're linearly independent, right?)

Can I just take $B_1 = \{(1,0,0),(0,2,-1)\}$ for $U$, and $B_2 = \{(0,1,-1)\}$ for $W$?

Thanks

Comment: Yes! The elements that span a space are basis elements if they're linearly independent. This is the case here, so your answer is correct.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. In general, to find a basis from a spanning set one completes the [sifting algorithm](http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~masbal/LinAlg1011/lectures.pdf) (see page 8).

Answer (score 1):

A [basis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_(linear_algebra)) $B$ of a [vector space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space) $V$ satisfies two properties:

- $B$ is linearly independent, and
- $\mathrm{span}(B)=V$.

In this case, we have $U=\mathrm{span}\{(1,0,0),(0,2,-1)\}$.

To verify that $B:=\{(1,0,0),(0,2,-1)\}$ is a basis for $U$, we need to check

1. $B$ is linearly independent. This is obvious by inspection -- the only solution to $a(1,0,0)+b(0,2,-1)=(0,0,0)$ is the trivial one.
2. $\mathrm{span}(B)=U$.  This is true by definition.

The case of $W$ is even easier.